# Spring boot SpringBootServletInitializer fails to autowire from XML Application Context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot application, I have an XML Application Context defined in XML which has a bunch of beans defined in it.  The bean of importance here is:

```
<bean id="MyAccessBean" class="com.company.MyAccessBean"> 
        <property name="ds" ref="ds"/>
        <property name="dsR" ref="dsr"/>
    </bean>
```

My application class skeleton is as follows:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   @Autowired
   MyAccessBean acBean

   @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<ReqLoggingFilter> reqLoggingFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<ReqLoggingFilter> regBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        ReqLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter = new ReqLoggingFilter();
        logger.info("acBean: " + acBean);
        requestLoggingFilter.setAccessBean(acBean);

        regBean.setFilter(requestLoggingFilter);
        regBean.addUrlPatterns("/foo/*");
        return regBean;
    }
}
```

The problem is that at the time in which the FilterRegistrationBean method gets called, the `MyAccessBean` hasn't been autowired yet, and as such is `null`.  I am using Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: add --debug parameter when you start MyApplication and check if Springboot loads the configuration

Comment: Add `MyAccessBean acBean`  as parameter to the `reqLoggingFilter` method. Also `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is already implied with `@SpringBootApplication` so remove it. You also have an `@ServletComponentScan` make sure that your `ReqLoggingFilter` isn't annotated with `@WebFilter` else you will get 2 instances of the filter.

Comment: Thank you M. Denium - adding acBean as parameter to reqLoggingFilter method did the trick!